# Validate Choice Field with multiselection Checkboxes on PreSaveAction function Call

Tags: javascript, list-form, sputility

My SharePoint 2010 list has a choice column that with checkboxes and allows multiple selections. For all these checkbox field choices there is a corresponding textbox fields are created. This textbox field is of type `SPNumberField`.

I want to validate these textboxes whenever user makes a check in the checkbox for null values.

I mean, assuming if the choice field values are:

- MS
- IBM
- SAP
- ORACLE
- SALESFORCE

and its corresponding textbox fields are "MS", "IBM" ...

If a user selects `IBM` and if the "IBM textbox" is empty, the user should not be able to save the form.

I tried using the `spUtility` and pure JavaScript, but it validates only for one checkbox which is selected by default, when the `mycustomnewform.aspx` is loaded.

When I selected other checkboxes and click the save button, the code is not getting executed.
 my below code:

```
 var compStatusChoiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Company');
 var compStatusChoiceFieldValue = compStatusChoiceField.GetValue();
 alert(compStatusChoiceFieldValue + '  == is the company value');
 var varIBM = SPUtility.GetSPField('IBM').GetValue();

 if(compStatusChoiceFieldValue == 'IBM')
        {
     if(varIBM == null || varIBM.length === 0)
      {
        flagGeneric = false;
        alert('IBM txtbox value is a mandatory!');
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple JavaScript to find whether the checkbox is checked, if yes, find the corresponding textbox and check if the textbox contains any value. Show an alert message to the users if there is no value.

Given below a sample JS code, modify the code based on your HTML format

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
var isValid="";

if(document.getElementById("#CheckBox1ID").checked == true)
{
var validationa = $('#TextBoxForCheckBox1ID').val();
if(validationa.length==0){
isValid += "CheckBox1";
}
}
if(document.getElementById("#CheckBox2ID").checked == true)
{
var validationb = $('#TextBoxForCheckBox2ID').val();
if(validationb.length==0){
isValid += "CheckBox2";
}
}
if(document.getElementById("#CheckBox3ID").checked == true)
{
var validationc = $('#TextBoxForCheckBox3ID').val();
if(validationc.length==0){
isValid += "CheckBox3";
}
}

if(isValid.length>0)
{
alert("This textbox corresponding to selected checkbox cannot be empty");
return false;
}

return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nagarajan, I already did the same , but its working for only ONE choice field. When I select multiselect check boxes and tried for the validation , it failed to validate other text boxes.I added the code, that I tried.Can you tell,how to get the ID of the ChoiceField? I do not want to take the ID which is generated at the viewsource or `F12 Developer Tools` as hardcoding that ID is not a recommended practice.

Comment: Try using the updated code

Comment: Can you tell, how can I get the  `#CheckBox1ID` ?

Comment: You can get it from your HTML content. Else, provide the html content of table where checkboxes and textbox are present.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/08/20/a-dummies-guide-to-sharepoint-and-jqueryndashgetting-amp-setting-sharepoint.aspx  this is helping me!