# Hide value(s) in choice field

Tags: edit-form, choice-field, survey

I would like hide (remove) the selections on edit form in Choice field type of Checkboxes, fox example there is 3 selections: Yes; Yes, but... and No. When I select  Yes or Yes, but..., I need hide No. And when I select No, I need hide Yes and Yes, but... It is in Survey list, so people can go back from other form and also there are question with the same selections where the selections cannot be hide.
I found this [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269724/hide-some-choice-value-based-on-current-choice-value-on-the-same-field-in-sharep) and [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159719/validate-choice-field-with-multiselection-checkboxes-on-presaveaction-function-c), but when I edit this for my need, it still does not work.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using modern experience or classic experience? Also, when you disable the options from choice fields, users will not be able to change their preference from Yes to No even if they want?

Comment: It is 2019 on premise with classic experience. And yes, users should be able to change their preference, when they will cancel selected option, hide option should be vissible again.